# Jquery to find more than one condition for items in a table

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a table like:

```
<table class="approvalstable"> 
  ... 
  <tr>
     <td class="projectapproval"> 
       <img src="../../Content/Images/stock_lock.gif" alt="locked" class="lockicon invisibleforprint" /> 
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="projectcheckbox approvalcheckbox" checked="checked" />
     </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="projectapproval"> 
        <img src="../../Content/Images/stock_lock.gif" alt="locked" class="lockicon invisibleforprint" />
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class="projectcheckbox approvalcheckbox" />
     </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="projectapproval">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class="projectcheckbox approvalcheckbox" />
     </td>
  </tr> 
  ... 
</table>
```

So far to get the number of rows without lock images in them I have:

```
$('.approvalstable td.projectapproval:not(:has(img.lockicon))').length
```

However I have a further requirement to only get the number of rows without lock images in them that also have a checked checkbox.

Ok so to get the number with checked checkboxes:

```
$('.projectcheckbox:checked').length;
```

Can anyone tell me how to combine them though? I'm trying to get the number of rows that have both no lock images in a cell and a checked checkbox in a cell within the same row.

Comment: are those td's supposed to be tr's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('tr').find('img.lockicon').parents('tr').find('input.projectcheckbox:checked').length
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QrXsx/)**.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.approvalstable td.projectapproval:not(:has(img.lockicon))').filter('.projectcheckbox:checked').length` should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think that will work because the checkbox and image are in seperate tds. Just added the trs to the question.